# best way to handle list of integers and to - find, add, and delete

Tags: go

I need to create a list of integers and to be able to quickly add, delete, and find items in that list. While I could create a string containing them and a function to handle the add/delete/locate, it obviously makes more sense if Go can handle it for me. I looked at container/list and it appeared not entirely suitable, but maybe I'm wrong.

To very quickly implement something, I am using an integer array, however that is far from ideal, and I need to find a better solution. The list will probably hold up to 1,000 values.

Can someone please advise the "best" way to handle this in Go? An example is worth 1,000 words.

Comment: Better how? What properties do you wish it to have? Do you want it to preserve the order of the items? Will you be mostly doing adds, or will adds and deletes be balanced? What will be the usual (rather than maximum) list size? What range will the ints be in? What's not ideal about your integer array? You're asking for optimisation but without providing specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interest of keeping it simple I would use a [map](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps).  Maps are very fast, efficient and built in.

([playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/oVoTaD9dff))

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // Make our collection of integers
    xs := make(map[int]bool)

    // Add some things to the collection
    xs[1] = true
    xs[2] = true
    xs[3] = true

    // Find them
    if xs[2] {
        fmt.Println("Found 2")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Didn't Find 2")
    }
    if xs[8] {
        fmt.Println("Found 8")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Didn't Find 8")
    }

    // Delete them
    delete(xs, 2)

    // List them
    for x := range xs {
        fmt.Println("Contents", x)
    }
}
```

Which produces

```
Found 2
Didn't Find 8
Contents 3
Contents 1
```

Possibly the only disadvantage of this solution is that the integers aren't kept in any particular order, which may or may not be important to your application.

Comment: there's no need to actually use a bool as value. `struct{}` (an empty struct) will do just fine.

Comment: I've changed my code to use the map as described. There are a few things that I don't like about the map solution, but they are no big deal.

Comment: @nick et al. (Edit time expired) I've changed my code to use the map as described. There are a few things that I don't like about the map solution, but they are no big deal. It is certainly easy to implement, I guess is fast, is flexible, is simple, and does what I need. Not sure why delete doesn't give a result, but at least I don't need to test for it. Do I need to use a value (bool), and if not, how, and is it worth it (no value)? As described below, all I really need to store is the "key" without a value in a "simple" list. Thanks, and I'll accept the answer soon.

Comment: @Brian Oh, You do need a value if using the builtin type `map` and there isn't a good alternative.  `bool` is the traditional one to use so you can test for existence with `if xs[2]` which is a convenience.  `bool`s are at least small. @nemo using `struct{}` will work but I think it [makes the code a lot more ugly](http://play.golang.org/p/bykOmu3Qu5) and not sure it actually saves you any space or not.

Comment: @Nick. OK, thanks for the info. It does appear to be the "best" way to handle it out-of-the-box. I don't want to be overly pedantic, so I won't labor any more over the bool.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood yes, it saves you memory. See [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/lb4xLHq7wug). It's not ugly if you create a type for it, e.g. `type empty struct{}`.

Comment: @nemo yes you are right about memory use with latest go [`map[int]bool` is 61MB](http://play.golang.org/p/qCK4KjB-iS) vs [`map[int]struct{}` 41MB](http://play.golang.org/p/mO56AWgwI4) so 32% less memory.

Answer (score 4):

There is no 'best' way to your question as you don't state what you would like to do or what 
sort of performance is important to you. The problem with data structures is, that every structure
performs better or worse depending on the circumstances. Generally I would say that an integer slice 
would perform reasonably well for 1000 entries and is not so hard to use. Also the solution Nick 
proposed is appealing, as it offers you `O(1)` lookup time (average!) for your values instead of 
`O(n)` (unsorted) or  `O(log n)` (sorted) search time in an array.

Go offers some operations to implement a `[]int` store as you proposed:

- **get**: `x[i]`
- **insert**: `x[i] = j` or `x = append(x, j)` or use sorted insertion
- **delete**: `x = append(x[:i], x[i+1:]...)`
- **search**: in case you used sorted insertion, you can use [`sort.SearchInts`](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#SearchInts), otherwise you need to loop and search linearly.

For more operations on slices see [here](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks).

The following example ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/s1c4wz5ZEe)) offers you a `[]int` 
with `O(log n)` time for searching and `O(n)` for insertion. Retrieval, deletion and setting 
by index is, of course, `O(1)`.

```
type Ints []int

// Insert v so that ints is sorted
func (ints *Ints) Append(v int) {
    i := sort.SearchInts(*ints, v)
    *ints = append((*ints)[:i], append([]int{v}, (*ints)[i:]...)...)
}

// Delete by index
func (ints *Ints) Delete(i int) {
    *ints = append((*ints)[:i], (*ints)[i+1:]...)
}

func (ints Ints) Search(v int) (int, bool) {
    i := sort.SearchInts(ints, v)
    return i, i < len(ints) && ints[i] == v
}

data := make(Ints, 0, 1000)
data.Append(100)
index,ok := data.Search(10)
```

As you can see in the example, `Append` searches for the place to insert the new value in, depending
on the size, effectively sorting the contents of the slice in ascending order. This makes it possible
to use binary search via `sort.SearchInts`, reducing the search time from `O(n)` to `O(log n)`.
With that comes the cost to sort while inserting, which in turn is done by searching for a slot, which
costs `O(log n)` in worst case. Therefore, inserting is `O(log n)` as well.

Comment: Your insertion looks like `O(n)` to me not `O(log n)` as you are inserting an element by copying the entire `[]int` slice. Nice example though.

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of an abstract data structure question. The answer depends on your use case. A slice of ints would do fine for the general case (look at `append` and such), but if you want finding items to be better than O(n) then you'll want them to be sorted, and insertion into a sorted `int[]` has a worst case of O(n) iirc.

So the question is which do you want to optimize, index, add, remove, or search?

Comment: Thanks all for answers. I would say search/remove are both important because they are both related. Order is of no importance. The sequence is add integer value to the "list", do some work, and delete it. Elsewhere (defer), check if value is there, if so, do something and delete it.

Comment: @BrianOh Are you sure your process can't be realized using channels? Sounds very similar to consumer/producer...

Comment: @nemo. I don't think that channels is the solution (I may be wrong). The Go program is an http server serving various clients. The "list" of integers contains a unique incremental id for each particular client. The update of database could abort at any time, and that is handled by a "defer"ed Rollback function call which is passed the unique id. If the update completes OK (commit), it deletes the int id from the "list". Therefore, when the Rollback function is called, if the unique id is not in the list, it simply returns. Otherwise, it does a Rollback and deletes the unique id from the list.

Comment: @BrianOh If you're using the list of integers plainly to tell the deferred function that the database update was OK, this may be overkill. You could store the database response in a closure which is deferred. See [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/M7AGJ3uTMl).

Comment: @nemo. Thanks, that looks like a good solution. I'll try it. At least I had an introduction to map which I hadn't had to use previously.